# Working With Tags for posts in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am working on a project that gives the user the ability to write a post then tag it. at the end other user comes in and votes for the best post.

everything was going like a charm until i faced the tagging challenge : how to work out the easiest way to deal with them ?

i used a many-to-many relationship to assign each post a number of tags. but i found difficulties before inserting them to the database. these difficulties included: 'how can i know that this tag is not already stored in DB ?'(of course i put the name field as UNIQUE, but if somebody entered a pre stored tag he will be faced with codeigniter error which i don't want it to be shown.) ..

So in short words, i came up with this solution :

1. Get All Tags from the DB.
2. Store the in array $all.
3. Get The User-Entered Tags.
4. Store Them in Array $user
5. Make an intersection $existed
6. in a foreach loop

   - Query the tags Table for the id of the current tag
   - Insert the ID in posts_has_tags table.
7. for the other array i would make another for each

   - Insert the tag into tags table.
   - Get the insert_id() $id
   - Insert the $id to the posts_has_tags table.

Well, i know that it's kind of mess. especially for looping in arrays which might be a little big with time ..  so, i am asking you guys :)
am i correct .. ? 
is there any easier way .. ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why should the tags actually need to be unique?

Comment: because i need more than one post to be tagged in a specific tag like travel..

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tags` WHERE `name`=:name_1 OR `name=:name_2 ...
```

Then, you can take the resultant tags and remove them from the user's tag array:

```
foreach ($user_tags as $tag) {
    if (!in_array($tag, $db_tags)) {
        $new_tags[] = $tag;
    }
}
```

You only have two queries this way, but I can't say how one might go about protecting this code from race conditions.